# Can apt upgrade a package but only if it's already installed?

Tags: debian, apt

Is there a way to use `apt` to apply a pending upgrade to a package, but do nothing if it's not installed?

I have many Debian systems, all with different sets of packages, and I want to apply specific patches as they become available.  I'd like to run the same command across all my systems *but* without installing missing packages.  Ordinarily I would use `apt-get install package` to do the upgrade, but this will install it where it's not already there.

I could work around this with something along the lines of

```
(dpkg -l package | grep '^ii') && apt-get install package
```

but is there a better way?

Comment: Just `apt-get upgrade` will not install missing packages. You want a version of `apt-get upgrade` that is package-specific? Like `apt-get upgrade pkgname`? if so, why?

Comment: I take a very conservative view to patching: I only apply patches where the fix is important to my servers.  Also, some patches can be applied without affecting production, where others require downtime (e.g. a postgresql patch will restart the database after it's applied).  I need a fine-graned approach so that I can apply important patches with minimal disruption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade pkgname
```

`man apt-get` says:

> ```
>  --only-upgrade
>      Do not install new packages; when used in conjunction with 
>      install, only-upgrade will install upgrades for already
>      installed packages only and ignore requests to install new
>      packages. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Only-Upgrade.
> ```

Comment: I am! Thanks so much -- for some reason I never saw that in the manpage.

Comment: @Flup Till just now, I didn't know it existed either. :-)